# Want to run Post-deployment script only once in AWS

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, unix, aws-code-deploy, aws-codepipeline

For codeDeployment script, we provide Before-Install, After-Install scripts.
My requirement is to run After-Install script only once i.e. the script should be deployed on the server only for the first time deployment.

Since the script is common, so it is wasting lots of time which is already present on the server.

Is there any way to skip this After-Install script for the further deployments??

In my case, I am doing "chown" for all the directories and files inside a directory in post deployment scripts.

Answer (score 0):

When you can not change the installation sequence, you can try two things.
1. Keep track of the deployments with some log

```
#!/bin/bash
phase4=/var/deploy4
if [ ! -f "${phase4}} ]; then
   echo "$(date) Installation started" > "${phase4}"
   # Do your thing
fi
```

2. Look to the things you are going to change

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   changeme="/some/path/to/some/initial/root/owned/file"
   if [ -n "$(find . -name "${changeme}" -user root)" ]; then
      echo "Running chown script"
      chown somebody "${changeme}"
   fi
   ```

Comment: Thank you so much.